# Optimize R nested loops with apply or similar

Tags: python, r, loops, optimization, apply

The code I show you here calculates exactly what I want, except for one problem: for large datasets, it takes just *TOO LONG*. Therefore, I was wondering if *there is an alternative solution using the apply() family or some other way*.

I always have a hard time to reexpress nested loops into vectorial functions. Do you think you could give me a hand? I would highly appreciate it ;)

So, before applying this nested loops I already have:

1. **2 dataframes**, called *"DATA"* and *"DATA_100_WELLS"*. From them, I only need variables *"WELL"* (categorical) and *"DELTA"* (numeric)
2. **3 global variables**, called ti, ta and tb, which will appear in the nested loops
3. A *"chosen_model"*, which I will use inside the function *"predict"*

Here it goes ... sorry if it´s hard to understand ...

```
#loop for each WELL from "DATA_100_WELLS"
for (WELL_PROCESS in unique(DATA_100_WELLS$WELL)) {
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #I take just 1 of the wells
  print("WELL------------------------------------------------------------")
  print(WELL_PROCESS)
  DATA_WELL <- DATA_100_WELLS[DATA_100_WELLS$WELL==WELL_PROCESS,] #select just the well I want

  #I calculate some stuff (Var_est0, sigma, linf, lsup, Za, Zb, n_ray and A)
  DATA_WELL$Var_est0 = predict(chosen_model,data.frame(predict=DATA_WELL$predict))
  DATA_WELL$sigma    = sqrt(DATA_WELL$Var_est0)
  DATA_WELL$linf     <- DATA_WELL$predict+DATA_WELL$sigma*ta
  DATA_WELL$lsup     <- DATA_WELL$predict+DATA_WELL$sigma*tb
  Za                 <- qnorm(alfa/2)
  Zb                 <- qnorm(1-alfa/2)
  n_ray              <- mean(DATA_WELL$predict)
  A                  =  sum(DATA_WELL$Var_est0)

  #Then i create an empty df called "TABLE", and slice off the heading
  TABLE<-data.frame(well="",d=0,p=0)
  TABLE<-TABLE[-1,]
  #After that, I iterate over each WELL from the second df, "DATA"
  for (well in unique(DATA$WELL)){
    print(paste("Process...: ",well,sep=""))
    #I calculate variable "large",based on max value of the existing variable "DELTA" (numeric)
    large = max(DATA[DATA$WELL==well,]$DELTA)
    #cicle from 1 max.distance (large-1)
    for (d in c(1:(large-1))){
      #cicle from position 1 to large-distance (look how this turns to be symmetric)
      for (pos in (1:(large-d))){
        #I did all of this to calculate variables ti and tj 
        ti = DATA[DATA$WELL==well & DATA$DELTA==pos,]$ti
        tj = DATA[DATA$WELL==well & DATA$DELTA==pos+d,]$ti
        #I append the results into the once empty df "TABLE", and calculate p based on ti*tj
        TABLE<-rbind(TABLE,data.frame(well=well,d=d,p=ti*tj))
      }
    }
  }
```

References:

1. *"WELL"* is a categorical variable, specifying names
2. *"DELTA"* is an already existent variable, present in both df
3. There are **4 loops in total**: first, for each WELL in df1. Second, for each WELL in df2. Third, for each distance in vector 1:(large-1). Finally, for each position in vector 1:(large-1), and do a symmetric calculation that is stored in df "TABLE".

That´s it. The solution could also be written in Python, if necessary.

Seriously, thank you!!

Comment: Without any sample data to test with, I am not going to even try to attempt this!  A couple of suggestions; do not bind inside a loop.  The bind command makes copies in memory and becomes a slow process when the data frames grows in size.  Second, instead of constantly checking/filtering by `DATA$WELL==well` use the split function to create a list of smaller data frames to use.  Performance will improve slightly do the smaller memory use and reducing the number of comparisons.  Finally, try to vectorize the inner loop, this will be the largest performance improvement.

Comment: No benchmarks, profiling, or [mcve]? I'm not sure how people are supposed to help.

Comment: The assumption that `apply` family functions are faster than `for` loops is usually wrong.  You won't see much improvement that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments it is difficult to help without a reproducible example though I'll give it a try. The following changes should speed things up:

1) do not rbind an object to itself repeatedly rather insert elements into a list and call bind_rows after the loops.

2) subset the DATA df into the wells_df for every well in the outer loop.

Even better than #2, but not implemented, you could split the DATA into a list by WELL ahead of the loops so you are only traversing DATA one time.

I did not run this code.

```
table_agg <- list()

for (well in unique(DATA$WELL)){
  print(paste("Process...: ",well,sep=""))
  #I calculate variable "large",based on max value of the existing variable "DELTA" (numeric)
  wells_df <- DATA[DATA$WELL==well,]
  large = max(wells_df$DELTA)
  #cicle from 1 max.distance (large-1)
  for (d in c(1:(large-1))){
    #cicle from position 1 to large-distance (look how this turns to be symmetric)
    for (pos in (1:(large-d))){
      #I did all of this to calculate variables ti and tj 
      ti = wells_df[wells_df$DELTA==pos,]$ti
      tj = wells_df[wells_df$DELTA==pos+d,]$ti
      #I append the results into the once empty df "TABLE", and calculate p based on ti*tj
      table_agg[[length(table_agg)+1]]<-data.frame(well=well,d=d,p=ti*tj)
    }
  }
}

TABLE <- dplyr::bind_rows(table_agg)
```

Comment: AMAZING! It´s incredible how much time is saved now. Thank you Patrick.
And thank you all for sharing. I will follow the orthodoxy next time. My apologies for that :)